# How to punch a hole in some 3D distribution of points

Tags: list-manipulation, geometry

Suppose we have a long list of 3D Cartesian coordinates, defining a distribution of random points in 3D space. How could we remove all the points inside a sphere of radius `sphereRadius` located at coordinates `sphereLocation = {X, Y, Z}`?

This Boolean subtraction is probably trivial, but I didn't found any useful info on how to do it with *Mathematica* 7.0.  Maybe it isn't trivial, after all.

---

**Generalisation :** How can we do the same with an arbitrary closed surface, instead of a sphere, if the hole is defined as a deformed sphere ?

```
holeLocation = {X, Y, Z};
hole[theta_, phi_] = holeLocation  + 
    radius[theta, phi] {Sin[theta]Cos[phi], Sin[theta]Sin[phi], Cos[theta]};
```

where `theta` and `phi` are the usual spherical coordinates.

Comment: Have a look at `Select` or `DeleteCases`, `EuclideanDistance` or `Norm`... For instance, using these, here's a box of points with the points falling within a sphere of radius 1/Sqrt@2 and center (1,1,1) missing http://i.stack.imgur.com/Rkoc7.png

Comment: `DeleteCases[points, p_ /; EuclideanDistance[p, {1, 2, 3}] < 10]`

Comment: What about the generalisation for a closed surface, with -Pi < theta < Pi and 0 < phi < 2 Pi ?

Comment: For speed,you can use my solution from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203910/select-points-within-a-circular-area-in-mathematica/7204117#7204117), which will be  faster than using `Norm` or `EuclideanDistance`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using [my solution to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203910/select-points-within-a-circular-area-in-mathematica/7204117#7204117) asked on StackOverflow some time ago,

```
Pick[dalist,UnitStep[criticalRadius^2-Total[(Transpose[dalist]-frameCenter)^2]],0]
```

which is for any number of (Euclidean) dimensions and should be quite fast.

**EDIT**

Ok, here is a generalization of the vectorized approach I proposed:

```
ClearAll[cutHole];
cutHole[relativeData_, holdRadiusF_] :=
  Module[{r, theta, phi, x, y, z},
    {x, y, z} = Transpose[relativeData];
    r = Sqrt[Total[relativeData^2, {2}]];
    theta = ArcCos[z/r];
    phi = ArcTan[x,y];
    Pick[relativeData, UnitStep[r - holdRadiusF[theta, phi]], 1]];
```

Here is an illustration:

```
data = RandomReal[6, {10^6, 3}];
holeLoc = {3, 3, 3};
relativeData = Transpose[ Transpose[data] - holeLoc];
```

Define some particular shape of the hole:

```
holeRad[theta_, phi_] := 1 + 4 Sqrt[Abs[Cos[theta]]]
```

Pick the points:

```
kept =cutHole[relativeData,holeRad];//AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.631836,Null}  *)
```

Visualize:

```
Show[{
  ListPointPlot3D[Cases[kept, {_, _, _?Positive}]], 
  SphericalPlot3D[
    holeRad[\[Theta], \[Phi]], {\[Theta], Pi/4, Pi/2}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi}, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Orange, Specularity[White, 10]], Mesh -> None]}]
```

[image]

The main point here is that the filtering function is vectorized and therefore quite fast.

Comment: I'm impressed with speed of the generalization--a big +1.

Comment: A plot? In Leonid's answer? o_O

Comment: @rm-rf The fact that my habits changed in the last few years  does not mean that I don't have the relevant experience. In fact, you'd be surprised :-).

Comment: @Leonid, your solution appears to work great on my system.  A question :  Can we make the hole fuzzy ?  i.e. can it be a distribution ?

Comment: @Leonid : I mean a fuzzy ball, instead of a sharp sphere, for example.  So the cut has smooth edges (fuzzy).

Comment: @Cham How do you define a notion to be inside or outside of such an object, for a given point?

Comment: @Leonid : Hmm, yep it's undefined.  Ok forget about it.  Anyway, your answer above is a complete solution to my question.  One hundred thanks !  :-)

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I guess what the OP wants is that within some radial range, the probability of dropping the points goes from one to zero?

Comment: @chris If you mean to allow points within some radial range to be kept or dropped probabilistically, then I can understand this, in such a formulation.

Comment: @whuber Thanks. The speedup comes from vectorization, to which functions such as `Norm` or `EuclideanDistance` are not directly amenable (`Norm` can be however compiled). I have been using similar constructs quite a bit in the past when dealing with similar problems.

Comment: I avoid `Norm`, etc., as well, for many reasons: but many of these functions are *more expressive,* which is advantageous when the coding is tricky or it is being used to convey ideas.  I have been making programming mistakes for so very long that my habit has been first to write code that clearly works, and only then--if it does not work fast enough--modify it for speed.

Comment: @whuber Actually, I totally agree. Normally, I follow the practice you described. So, your answer really deserves to be accepted, not mine.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `phi = ArcTan[x, y];`?

Answer (score 9):

Because the question refers to points using both Cartesian coordinates $(x,y,z)$ and spherical coordinates $(\theta, \phi)$, we need to convert between them:

```
spherical[{x_, y_, z_}] := {ArcTan[z, Norm[{x, y}]], ArcTan[x, y]};
```

A point `p` is inside the "hole" when its distance from the origin (computed with `Norm`) is less than the value given by the function `radius`.  For flexibility, I have included an optional argument `threshold` that multiplies the value of `radius`:

```
inside[p_, origin_, radius_, threshold_: 1] :=  
  threshold radius @ spherical @ (p - origin) >= Norm[p - origin];
```

Use this to `Select` the points inside the hole (or, by negating `inside`, to exclude them):

```
pointsInside = Select[points, inside[#, origin = {0, 0, 0}, radius] &];
```

(I have chosen an origin of `{0,0,0}` for this example to make it easy to plot the hole using `SphericalPlot3D`.)

---

#### Example

Let's define a hole to illustrate:

```
radius[{\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_}] := (1 + Cos[\[Theta]]^2) (1 + Sin[ \[Phi]]^2);
```

We will need some points:

```
points = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {3000, 3}];
```

For the illustration, let's plot all those points, distinguishing those inside the hole from those outside it:

```
pointPlot = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.3], Gray, Point @ points, 
  PointSize[0.01], Red, Opacity[0.5], Point @ pointsInside, 
  Black, Opacity[1], Point @ origin}];
```

Here is the hole's boundary for reference:

```
hole = SphericalPlot3D[radius[{\[Theta], \[Phi]}], {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]},
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.25], Mesh -> None]
```

Put them together:

```
Show[pointPlot, hole]
```

[image: Figure]

Comment: Why the **threshold** parameter ?

Comment: So you can vary the size of the hole while fixing its basic shape: it gives you an easy way to create a succession of layers of points, like rings of an onion, without having to change the definition of `radius`.

Comment: Aah !  Yes, good point !  Thanks.