# Fastest way to calculate matrix of pairwise distances

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, programming

It is a very common problem that given a distance function $d(p_1,p_2)$ and a set of points `pts`, we need to construct a matrix `mat` so that `mat[[i,j]] == d[ pts[[i]], pts[[j]] ]`.

What is the most efficient way to do this in Mathematica?

---

Let's assume that the points are in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for simplicity, and because that's the case I'm dealing with now, but theoretically the points could be any type of object, e.g. strings with $d$ being an edit distance.

For the specific problem I have right now I need to calculate the `EuclideanDistance` and `ManhattanDistance` of 2D points.

The simplest way to do this is

```
pts = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {1000, 2}];

mat = Outer[ManhattanDistance, pts, pts, 1]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* ==> {0.595327, Null} *)
```

This obviously calculates all distances twice, which is wasteful.  So I was hoping for an easy $2\times$ speedup, but it isn't as easy as one would hope.  Doing the same operation the same number of times in a `Do` loop takes considerably longer (probably because of indexing):

```
Do[ManhattanDistance[pts[[10]], pts[[20]]], {Length[pts]^2}]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* ==> {1.902417, Null} *)
```

So what programming pattern do you typically use when calculating such a distance matrix and which one would you recommend for this specific problem?

Comment: There are of course lots of different ways to do the calculation.  Unfortunately it is not at all obvious which is likely to be the fastest.

Comment: related : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19334/is-table-the-only-functional-way-to-construct-nested-loops-in-mathematica/19336#19336

Comment: Good question, just what I was looking for at the moment! I also wonder, how much speed can be gained if only the distance functions is reimplemented & compiled?

Comment: I just want to point out that most of the answers (using the vectorized speedup) won't work for the more general case (e.g. Hamming distance of vectors, edit distance of strings, etc.). If one does not want to desing a specific, highly optimized method for each such case, I found that using `Outer` is generally the fastest way.

Comment: Why not generate all the entries in, say, the lower triangle (with something like `Table[(* stuff *), {j, n}, {k, j}] // Flatten`) and feed this to `SymmetrizedArray[]`? (I do not have version 9, so I can't test this.)

Comment: @J.M or `tri = {(* lower triangle *)}; full = tri + Transpose@tri*(1-IdentityMatrix@n)`. Or if the diagonal is assumed to be zero (in case of most distance functions), the `1-IdentityMatrix@n` part can be omitted.

Comment: @IstvánZachar, what are the preconditions and limits of vectorization? The book "Dictionary of Distances" lists hundreds of families of metrics, including Earth Mover Distance b/w two histograms which requires solving a LP - ie not likely vectorizable. So what are the limits?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Using `Outer` is here one of the worst methods, and not just because it computes the distance twice, but because you can't leverage vectorization in this approach. This is actually a common issue and an important point to stress: *`Outer` works pairwise and is unable to utilize the possible vectorized nature of the operation it is performing on an element-by-element basis*.

Here is the code I will adopt from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/637/character-edge-finding/639#639):

```
distances=
   With[{tr=Transpose[pts]},
     Function[point,Sqrt[Total[(point-tr)^2]]]/@pts
   ];//AbsoluteTiming

(*  {0.046875,Null} *)
```

which is an order of magnitude faster. You can `Compile` it with a C target which may improve the performance further. Also, essentially the same approach I used in [this recent answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21729/how-to-punch-a-hole-in-some-3d-distribution-of-points/21730#21730), with good performance.

For Manhattan distance, use

```
distances = 
   With[{tr = Transpose[pts]}, 
      Function[point, Total@Abs[(point - tr)]] /@ pts];
```

**EDIT**

As noted by Ray Koopman in comments, the function `DistanceMatrix` from the package `` HierarchicalClustering` `` may be faster for Euclidean distance, for small and medium data size (up to a couple of thousands):

```
Sqrt[HierarchicalClustering`DistanceMatrix[pts, DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance]];// AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.019351, Null} *)
```

<del>Note, however, that this is only true for the particular case of Euclidean distance, or perhaps other distances which don't require to set the `DistanceFunction` option explicitly on the top-level. In other cases (for example, for Manhattan distance), it will be quite slow, because when `DistanceFunction` is set explicitly, one can not leverage vectorization any more, once again.</del> In recent versions of Mathematica it is optimized for several possible `DistanceFunction` settings, including `ManhattanDistance`.

Comment: I had not taken apart the previous code. This is impressive. Even when you consider that it is performing the calculation twice as often as required. +1

Comment: @rcollyer Thanks. What "previous code" do you mean though? I actually did not want to get the absolute fastest (otherwise would go with `Compile`), but wanted to stress this issue with `Outer` and explain why it is slow here.

Comment: Seeing as I goofed up the dimensions, I pulled out an old MATLAB code of mine for a vectorized solution to aim for speed (I had forgotten what I had done) and it was more or less identical to this :)

Comment: @rm-rf Well, that's a cool compliment, since it comes from Matlab guru :-).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I really think Mathematica is too hard to learn right and that hinders adoption.

Comment: @RolfMertig Yes, I agree. But I would think that this "hard to learn" thing is due to the complexity of evaluation process. I have been long saying that some intermediate linguistic layer which would shield people from this complexity would be good.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Also better debugging. Just trying to write some kind of post-processor: redefine argument-less SetDelayed's to proper argument-ones. More difficult than it should be (and all this to make Mathematica look like Mathcad ... (and to save carrying along a lot of arguments by hand))

Comment: @RolfMertig Not so sure about debugging. I mean, sure some better tools would be great, I am just not sure that such tools should have much in common with more traditional debuggers. Debuggers are much more useful for statement-based languages which manipulate state, in my opinion. Re: SetDelayed - my condolences :).

Comment: Pre-complementing saves some time: `With[{tr = -Transpose@pts}, Total@Abs[# + tr]& /@ pts]`. Also, for "small" problems, say < 1700 or so points (on my system -- YMMV), the built-in `DistanceMatrix` function in the `HierarchicalClustering` package seems to be faster. I'm puzzled why it hasn't been mentioned. Are people not aware of it?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @Ray. I did not see any particular speedup from pre-complementing on my system, but `DistanceMatrix` with the default `DistanceFunction` is indeed faster in the range you specified, for Euclidean distances. I wasn't aware of that. But also, this is only true when we can avoid explicitly specifying `DistanceFunction` - please see my edit.

Answer (score 24):

Here is a little procedural implementation using `Bag`, compiled to `C`:

```
distmatrix = Compile[{{pts, _Real, 2}},
   Block[{x, y, list = Internal`Bag[Most[{0.}]]},
    For[x = 1, x <= Length[pts], x++,
     For[y = x + 1, y <= Length[pts], y++,
       Internal`StuffBag[list, 
         Abs[Compile`GetElement[pts, x, 1] - 
            Compile`GetElement[pts, y, 1]] + 
          Abs[Compile`GetElement[pts, x, 2] - 
            Compile`GetElement[pts, y, 2]]];
       ];
     ];
    Internal`BagPart[list, All]
    ], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];

distmatrix[pts]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*

{0.009000, Null}

*)
```

**edit**: an even better performing solution is based on Mr. Wizard's vectorization approach and relying on the listability and parallelizability of compiled functions, and as a nice touch, it doesn't rely on undocumented functions.

```
distmatrix2 = 
  Compile[{{point, _Real, 1}, {tr, _Real, 2}}, 
   Total @ Abs[point - tr], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
   Parallelization -> True];
```

For comparison against Leonid's method, let's use more points.

```
pts = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {10000, 2}];

distmatrix[pts]; // AbsoluteTiming

distances = 
   With[{tr = Transpose[pts]}, 
     Function[point, Total@Abs[(point - tr)]] /@ pts]; // AbsoluteTiming

distmatrix2[pts, Transpose[pts]]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.865050, Null}, {1.562089, Null},  {0.319018, Null} *)
```

It seems that the simple procedural implementation is a bit less than twice as fast, and not really worth the extra work/complexity. The listable/parallelized compiled solution is simpler and about 5x faster.

Comment: Can you run a comparison against Leonid's code, as my timings differ from yours? (Yours is still faster ...)

Comment: +1 still. The reason why it is hard to make the code much more efficient particularly for large lists is that the larger the list, the closer is the performance of my code to the low-level C performance. This is because what matters always is to make fast inner loops - and in my case the inner loop is replaced by a vectorized operation. The longer the list, the more the bottleneck is in the vectorized operation, and you can't get much faster here since those are highly optimized.

Comment: Where can I find information about `Internal\`*`, `Compile\`*` etc.? It doesn't appear to be in any standard documentation. I find it unfair that WRI hides so much these useful internal features. They will always be able to produce more efficient code if they have such tools available.

Comment: @Federico, unfortunately they are undocumented. I figured out how to use them from this site, see: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1934/efficiently-collecting-results-inside-a-compiled-function & http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/how-do-i-check-if-any-element-in-a-list-is-positive/8872#8872

Answer (score 20):

The [`DistanceMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DistanceMatrix.html) function, newly introduced in version 10.3, is very fast for Euclidean distances.

Here's a speed comparison with Leonid's fast solution.

```
pts = RandomReal[1, {5000, 2}];
```

**Euclidean**

```
dm1 = With[{tr = Transpose[pts]}, Function[point, Sqrt[Total[(point - tr)^2]]] /@ pts]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.952627, Null} *)

dm2 = DistanceMatrix[pts, pts]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.212496, Null} *)

dm3 = HierarchicalClustering`DistanceMatrix[pts, DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.582991, Null} *)

dm1 == dm2 == dm3
(* True *)
```

Note that `` HierarchicalClustering`DistanceMatrix `` is a *built-in function*, not one provided by the package.  Most performance-critical functions of this "package" are in reality highly optimized built-ins.  Also note that the default distance for this function is not `EuclideanDistance`, but that square of that.  So we needed to specify `EuclideanDistance` explicitly.

**Manhattan**

Let's test if these functions are special-cased for the Manhattan distance.

```
dm1 = 
   With[{tr = Transpose[pts]}, 
    Function[point, Total@Abs[(point - tr)]] /@ pts]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.801177, Null} *)

dm2 = 
   DistanceMatrix[pts, pts, 
    DistanceFunction -> ManhattanDistance]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.211771, Null} *)

dm3 = 
   HierarchicalClustering`DistanceMatrix[pts, 
    DistanceFunction -> ManhattanDistance]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.621123, Null} *)

dm1 == dm2 == dm3
(* True *)
```

**A final note**

For accurate benchmarking is it very important to use `AbsoluteTiming` and not `Timing` here. In recent versions of Mathematica all of these operations are internally parallelized and `Timing` would measure the total CPU time spent by each core, added up, instead of the wall time.

---

Just for fun, here's a C++ version using [LTemplate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96127/12).  This is specialized for 2D points!

```
<< LTemplate`
```

I'm on a Mac where the system compiler doesn't support OpenMP.  I'll use gcc from MacPorts to be able to use OpenMP.

```
$CCompiler = {"Compiler" -> CCompilerDriver`GenericCCompiler`GenericCCompiler, 
   "CompilerInstallation" -> "/opt/local/bin", 
   "CompilerName" -> "g++-mp-5", 
   "SystemCompileOptions" -> 
    "-O3 -m64 -fPIC -framework Foundation -framework mathlink"};

SetDirectory[$TemporaryDirectory];
code = "
  #include <cmath>

  inline double sqr(double x) { return x*x; }

  struct DistMatrix {
    mma::RealTensorRef distMat(mma::RealMatrixRef a, mma::RealMatrixRef b) {
        mma::RealMatrixRef mat = mma::makeMatrix<double>(a.rows(), b.rows());
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for (mint i=0; i < a.rows(); ++i)
            for (mint j=0; j < b.rows(); ++j)
                mat(i, j) = std::hypot(a(i,0) - b(j,0), a(i,1) - b(j,1));
        return mat;
    }
  };
  ";
Export["DistMatrix.h", code, "String"];


tem = LClass[
   "DistMatrix", 
    {LFun["distMat", {{Real, 2, "Constant"}, {Real, 2, "Constant"}}, {Real, 2}]}
];

CompileTemplate[tem, 
 "CompileOptions" -> {"-std=c++14", "-fopenmp"}]

LoadTemplate[tem]

obj = Make["DistMatrix"];

dm4 = obj@"distMat"[pts, pts]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.062397, Null} *)

dm1 == dm4
(* True *)
```

Comment: Hello, Szabolcs. I always wanted to learn **Wolfram  Library link** technique. However, for the beginer(like me), I discovered that it is not easy(**hard**) for me to learn that via the **Wolfram LibraryLink User Guide**. Could you give some suggestions to beginer to let them understand that technique more easily? Thanks a bunch:)

Answer (score 9):

This is another vectorized approach which is an order of magnitude faster than using `Outer`, but about 1.5 times slower than Leonid's answer:

```
dist = With[{c = ConstantArray[Dot[#, #] & /@ pts, {Length@pts}]},
    c + Transpose@c - 2 pts . Transpose@pts // Sqrt];
```

Answer (score 7):

This is a good case that can sped up with `FunctionCompile`. My starting point is Leonid's code from his accepted answer:

```
pts = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {10000, 2}];

AbsoluteTiming[
 d1 = With[{tr = Transpose[pts]}, 
    Function[point, Sqrt[Total[(point - tr)^2]]] /@ pts];]
```

Gives: {1.7097, Null}

Write the code as a function, with typed arguments:

```
f = 
  Function[{Typed[pts, TypeSpecifier["PackedArray"]["Real64", 2]]},
   With[{tr = Transpose[pts]}, Map[Sqrt[Total[(# - tr)^2]] &, pts]]];

AbsoluteTiming[d2 = f[pts];]
```

Gives a similar timing: {1.70066, Null}

Use `FunctionCompile` to compile it:

```
cf = FunctionCompile[f];

AbsoluteTiming[d3 = cf[pts];]
```

Gives a 2-3x speedup: {0.51376, Null}

Check that all the results are the same:

```
d1 == d2 == d3
```

Gives: True