# Generating a graph where vertices correspond to points in an integer lattice and edges connect points less than a threshold distance apart

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I'd like to automatically generate a graph where vertices correspond to (and have the coordinates of) points in an $A \times B$ integer lattice, and a graph is generated by connected vertices within a real-valued cutoff distance $r$.  Is there a (relatively) automated manner of doing this in Mathematica v9?  How can we display this graph properly, respecting the vertex coordinates?

Comment: What is a "random _geometric_ graph"?

Comment: @belisarius That was a foolish mistake.  I meant that the rules for connecting vertices should be the same as in a random geometric graph (connect vertices if the distance between them is $\leq r$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make an integer lattice:

```
pts = Tuples[Range[10], 2]; (* maybe you want Tuples[{A,B}] *)
```

[Find pairwise distances:](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21861/fastest-way-to-calculate-matrix-of-pairwise-distances)

```
distances = 
  With[{tr = N@Transpose[pts]}, 
   Function[point, Sqrt[Total[(point - tr)^2]]] /@ pts];
```

Construct the graph:

```
threshold = 2;
SimpleGraph[AdjacencyGraph@UnitStep[threshold - distances], VertexCoordinates -> pts]
```

`SimpleGraph` is used to get rid of self loops.

Comment: Works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

By using Graph primitives.

```
g = GridGraph[{8, 9}];
vc = PropertyValue[{g, #}, VertexCoordinates] & /@ VertexList[g];
g1 = EdgeDelete[g, EdgeList[g]];
g2 = Fold[SetProperty[{#1, #2[[1]]}, VertexCoordinates -> #2[[2]]] &, 
                                                               g1, Transpose[{VertexList[g], vc}]]
cutoff = N@Sqrt[2];
f = Nearest[vc -> Automatic];
allEdgeSet = f[#, {Infinity, cutoff}] & /@ vc;
formattedEdges = Thread[UndirectedEdge[#[[2 ;;]], #[[1]]]] & /@ allEdgeSet;
randomEdges = DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ Flatten[RandomSample[#, 2] & /@ formattedEdges]];
EdgeAdd[g2, randomEdges]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using?  For some reason, copy pasting this code, and using a fresh kernel, `GridGraph` is colored red and doesn't seem to work?

Comment: @user10456 Mathematica v9. GridGraph was introduced in version 8

Comment: I owe you an apology, I left in a line asking the Combinatorica package to load.  Removing it fixed the problem.

Comment: @user10456 Yep, that's a common problem. "Combinatorica clashes" :)

Answer (score 2):

## General solution

I propose a general multidimensional solution with possibility to set periodic boundary conditions (I use a similar function in my own problem).

```
lattice[L_List, r_: 1] := 
 With[{d = Length[L], LL = Reverse@FoldList[Times, 1, Reverse@Abs@L][[1 ;; -2]]},
  With[{δ = Pick[#, UnitStep[# - 1] UnitStep[r^2 - #] &@Total[#^2, {2}], 1] &@
    Tuples[Range[-#, #] &@Ceiling[r], d]},
   Module[{Id = Join @@ Table[Transpose[{#, # + δ[[i]]}, {2, 3, 1}], {i, Length[δ]}] &@
     Transpose@Tuples[Range /@ Abs[L]] - 1},
    Do[If[L[[i]] > 0, 
      Id = Pick[Id, UnitStep[#] UnitStep[L[[i]] - 1 - #] &@Id[[All, 2, i]], 1],
      Id[[All, All, i]] = Mod[Id[[All, All, i]], -L[[i]]]], {i, d}];
    SparseArray[1 + Id.LL -> ConstantArray[1, Length[Id]]]
   ]]]
```

It returns the adjacency matrix for lattice with dimensions `L` (e.g. {10,5}).

## Examples

1D lattice with 10 vertices

```
AdjacencyGraph@lattice[{10}]
```

[image]

1D lattice with 10 vertices with periodic boundary conditions (denoted by negative lengths)

```
AdjacencyGraph@lattice[{-10}]
```

[image]

1D lattice with 10 vertices with periodic boundary conditions and `r = 2` (default value is 1)

[image]

$a\times b$ 2D lattice (OP's question)

```
a = 10;
b = 5;
r = 1.5;
AdjacencyGraph[lattice[{a, b}, r], 
 VertexCoordinates -> Join @@ Outer[List, Range[a], Range[b]]]
```

[image]

2D lattice with one periodic boundary

```
AdjacencyGraph@lattice[{10, -10}]
```

[image]

[Tesseract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract)

```
AdjacencyGraph@lattice[{2, 2, 2, 2}]
```

[image]

## Notes

You can delete `UnitStep[# - 1]` to produce self-loops

[image]

It is fast for very big lattices ($1\,000\,000\times1\,000\,000$ adjacency matrix!)

```
lattice[{1000, 1000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {2.718346, Null}

Szabolcs's approach with pairwise distances inapplicable for such lattices.

`lattice` uses packed array for big lattices. You can check it by `On["Packing"]`.