# Finding the volume of a sphere using the Monte Carlo algorithm

Tags: numerical-integration, random, simulation

I used the following code to find the volume of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 1$ in the first octant:

```
McVolume[Num_] := 
 Module[{hit, miss, index, x, y, z}, hit = 0; miss = 0;    
  For[index = 1, index <= Num, index = index + 1,    
   x = Random[Real, {0, 1}];    
   y = Random[Real, {0, 1}];    
   z = Random[Real, {0, 1}];    
   If[z <= Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2], hit = hit + 1, miss = miss + 1];];    
  Return[(hit/Num) 1];]  

McVolume[100]
```

It turns out to be `11/25`. Even thought the answer is correct but using this code i am getting an error:

> LessEqual::nord: Invalid comparison with 0. +0.48202 I attempted. >>

I don't understand, why is this error popping up?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The programming style you are using is not very fitting for Mathematica.  Here's a better way (shorter, much faster):

```
n = 1000000; (* number of points to use *)
octantVolume = N[ Total@UnitStep[1 - Norm /@ RandomReal[1, {n, 3}]]/n ]
```

---

The reason why you get the error you mention is that for some `x`, `y`, the expression `1 - x^2 - y^2` is negative, thus its square root is not a real number and can't be use in inequalities.  Use `If[x^2+y^2+z^2 <= 1^2, ...]` instead.

Comment: +1 for providing an answer to the actual question.

Answer (score 18):

Method of random number generation is also significant:

Default:

```
n = 10^6;
AbsoluteTiming[N@Mean@UnitStep[1. - Total[RandomReal[1, {3, n}]^2]] - π/6]
```

> {0.197896, **0.000649224**}

Niederreiter low-discrepancy sequence (see "methods" [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/RandomNumberGeneration.html)):

```
SeedRandom[Method -> {"MKL", Method -> {"Niederreiter", "Dimension" -> 3}}];
AbsoluteTiming[N@Mean@UnitStep[1. - Total[RandomReal[1, {n, 3}]^2, {2}]] - π/6]
```

> {0.139869, **0.0000132244**}

Precision is >10 times better. It is equivalent to increasing the random sequence by 100-1000 times!

Comment: To give an analogy with `NIntegrate[]`, the second approach is equivalent to using `"QuasiMonteCarlo"`, while the first one is akin to using `"MonteCarlo"`.

Answer (score 17):

When `n` is large it's much faster to operate on a 3 x `n` array than to process each of the `n` 3-vectors separately. This is one of the standard "tricks" to speed things up.

```
n = 10^6;  (*  Isn't that easier to read than 1000000 ?  *)

AbsoluteTiming @ N[ Total@UnitStep[ 1. - Norm/@RandomReal[1,{n,3}] ]/n ]
(* {4.555842, 0.524302} *)

AbsoluteTiming @ N[ Total@UnitStep[ 1. - Total[ RandomReal[1,{3,n}]^2 ] ]/n ]
(* {0.908908, 0.523554} *)
```

Comment: +1. [This question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21861/fastest-way-to-calculate-matrix-of-pairwise-distances/) (and my answer there, as well as further links in there) seem related.

Comment: +1. A bit more compact: `N@Mean@UnitStep...`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried several ways to save time and make it more effective:

```
McVol1[num_] :=
    Module[{hit, miss, index, x, y, z}, hit = 0; miss = 0;
    For[index = 1, index <= num, ++index, {x, y, z} = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3];
    If[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1, ++hit]];
    hit/num]
    Print["time and value...... :", Timing[N@McVol1[100000]]]
```

Result is

> ```
> time and value...... :{0.452403, 0.52286}
> ```

The second is more effective

```
 McVol2[num_] :=
    Plus @@ Table[Boole[Norm[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3]] <= 1], {num}]/num
    Print["time and value...... :", Timing[N@McVol2[100000]]]
```