# Monte Carlo Method

Tags: pattern-matching, assignment

How do you use a Monte Carlo method to approximate the area enclosed by the circle.

Comment: Did you see these items https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37074/finding-the-area-of-a-circle-using-monte-carlo-simulation and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35683/finding-the-volume-of-a-sphere-using-the-monte-carlo-algorithm?

Answer (score 3):

Literally the Monte Carlo `Method`:

```
reg = RegionIntersection[Disk[], Disk[{1, 1}, 2]];
NIntegrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] reg, Method -> "MonteCarlo"]
(*  2.59499  *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
rndPts = Table[RandomReal[{-3, 3}],{10^6},{2}];
9 Length[Select[
    rndPts, #[[1]]^2 + #[[2]]^2 > 
       1 && (#[[1]] - 1)^2 + (#[[2]] - 1)^2 < 4 &]]/Length[rndPts]
```

2.51295

[image]