# Filter two lists of 2D coordinates such that only those that have a nearby neighbour in the other list are collected

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two sets of coordinates:

[GreenPairs.xls](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8hvudjsu5usqt9u/GreenPairs.xls?dl=0)

[RedPairs.xls](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8gu4k67twfqzs85/RedPairs.xls?dl=0)

I'm only interested in the coordinates that have a very close (overlapping in the plot below) different coloured neighbour.  The threshold distance isn't precise, just small relative to the spread of the other points.  I need to be able to do this for about a million other similar sets of coordinates so efficiency is reasonably important.

The solution should provide a list of red points and a list of green points.  Every one of which must have a exactly one neighbour in the other list.  It's not necessary to know exactly which points pair together.

[image: RedPairs and GreenPairs]

Comment: You might also want to look at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21861/fastest-way-to-calculate-matrix-of-pairwise-distances

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathematica wasn't easily importing your example data from dropbox so I started by generating some random data.

```
green = RandomReal[1000, {100, 2}];
red = RandomReal[1000, {100, 2}];
```

Now we can compute `NearestFunctions` for both datasets.

```
nfgreen = Nearest@green;
nfred = Nearest@red;
```

And using `Select` to determine which points are close (defined arbitrarily as `EuclideanDistance <= 10`)

```
Select[red, EuclideanDistance[#, First@nfgreen[#, 1]] <= 10 &]
Select[green, EuclideanDistance[#, First@nfred[#, 1]] <= 10 &]
```

You might be able to speed this up using `Pick` instead of select or clever use of `Compile` but I haven't played around much and I'm on a slow laptop.

Comment: There is no need to use `Select`. One can just use `Flatten[nfred[#, {All, 10}] & /@ green, 1]` and `Flatten[nfgreen[#, {All, 10}] & /@ red, 1]`.

Comment: @Karsten7.: Won't that produce duplicate copies of any red point is within 10 units of *two* green points (and vice versa)?

Comment: Can be fixed with `Union` or `DeleteDuplicates`.

Comment: @Rahul Yes. And could either remove duplicates, as [shrx commented](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98605/filter-two-lists-of-2d-coordinates-such-that-only-those-that-have-a-nearby-neigh/98610?noredirect=1#comment267460_98610), or  use this fact to remove all points having more than one neighbor (and therefore also not exactly one).