# A quicker than outer

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, performance-tuning

I need to get a matrix $\{a(x_i-x_j)\}$, where $x_i$ form a partition of an interval, $a(x)$ is a given function. I use

```
In[67]:= a[x_?NumericQ] := N[Exp[-Abs[x]]];
         x = Table[-10 + 0.02 (j - 1), {j, 1, 1001}];
         A = Outer[a[#1 - #2] &, x, x]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[69]= {2.99032, Null}
```

I think it spends too much time. A modification

```
In[209]:= B = Partition[Map[a, Flatten[Outer[#1 - #2 &, x, x]]], 1001]; // AbsoluteTiming
Out[209]= {2.88966, Null}
```

does not help too much as well. Can I do this faster?

Comment: The ideas from Leonid's answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21861/12) should be applicable to your problem as well.  Try to vectorize, i.e. do arithmetic on vectors instead of scalars.

Comment: `Exp[-Abs[x - #]] & /@ x` is faster than 0.02 seconds on my machine.

Comment: FWIW, the new `DistanceMatrix[]` function might be useful here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Vectorization will help a lot:

```
a[x_?NumericQ] := N[Exp[-Abs[x]]];
x = Table[-10 + 0.02 (j - 1), {j, 1, 1001}];
A = Outer[a[#1 - #2] &, x, x]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {2.11988, Null} *)

B = Exp[-Abs[x - #]] & /@ x; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.016182, Null} *)

A == B
(* True *)
```

Notice that I am doing arithmetic on vectors the size of `x` instead of scalars.  This is much faster than element-wise computation.

The idea is from Leonid's answer here:

- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21863/12

Comment: However, if you use a[x] directly the difference will not be so significant, I guess: `SetAttributes[a, Listable]; B = a[x - #] & /@ x; // AbsoluteTiming`

Comment: @Dmitri By setting `a` to be `Listable`, you are essentially preventing vectorization.  Arithmetic will once again be done element by element.

Comment: Sorry, I have to say RTFM to myself :-)

Comment: @Szabolcs This gives 2x further speed up: `c = Exp[-Abs[x - # & /@ x]];/`

Comment: I'm not really used to the term vectorization in this context, but should it really exclude using listable functions? My timings indicate that `(res2 = Thread[Unevaluated@Subtract[a, b]]) // AbsoluteTiming // First` is 4 times faster than `a-b` for random reals, which appears to "do arithmetic element by element". Interestingly, the version with `Thread` seems to parallelise automatically.

Comment: Sorry for my poor choice of variable names

Answer (score 18):

`Outer` is highly optimized for several built-in functions (`Plus`, `Times`, `List`). Therefore

```
Exp@-Abs@Outer[Plus, #, -#] &@Range[-10, 10, 0.02]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.025, Null} *)
```

gives ~50x speedup over `Outer[#1 - #2&, #, #]` and ~15x speedup over `Outer[Subtract, #, #]`. Also is a bit faster then Kuba's `Exp[-Abs[x - # & /@ x]]`.

Comment: Gosh, I remembered `Outer` being fast, but forgot it was only in special cases.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, two things help. The first is that `Subtract` is going to execute faster than `#1 - #2 &`, and the other is that all the operations involved in `a` are `Listable`, so getting rid of that `_?NumericQ` restriction speeds things up greatly. On my computer, this amounts to an order of magnitude speedup:

```
With[{x = Table[-10 + 0.02 (j - 1), {j, 1, 1001}]},
   Outer[a[#1 - #2] &, x, x]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {2.29455, Null} *)

With[{x = Table[-10 + 0.02 (j - 1), {j, 1, 1001}]},
   a[Outer[Subtract, x, x]]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.213449, Null} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

It appears `Outer` can be reasonably compiled to C.

```
cfu = Compile[
  {{x, _Real, 1}}
  ,
  Outer[Exp[-Abs[# - #2]] &, x, x]
  ,
  CompilationTarget -> "C"
  ]
```

Timings

```
A = cfu@x; // RepeatedTiming
B = Exp[-Abs[x - #]] & /@ x; // RepeatedTiming
A === B
```

> ```
> {0.014,Null}
> {0.020,Null}
> True
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
Exp@-Abs@Outer[#1 - #2 &, #, #] &[Range[-10, 10, 0.02]]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.950001

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from @Leonid Shifrin's approach, we can create a slightly better version than `Outer` gaining some improvement if not a lot

with built-in `Outer` and `a` as `Listable`:

```
SetAttributes[a, Listable];
a[x_?NumericQ] := N[Exp[-Abs[x]]];
x = Table[-10 + 0.02 (j - 1), {j, 1, 1001}];
(b = a[Outer[#1 - #2 &, x, x]];) // RepeatedTiming
(* 2.62 seconds *)
```

defining our own version of `Outer`

```
ourOuter[f_, arg1_, arg2_] := Module[{auxf},
Attributes[auxf] = {Listable};
auxf[x_][y_] := f[x, y];
Through[auxf[arg1][arg2]]
];

ClearAll[a];
SetAttributes[a, Listable];
a[x_] := N[Exp[-Abs[x]]];

(c = With[{x = Table[-10 + 0.02 (j - 1), {j, 1, 1001}]},
a[ownOuter[Subtract, x, x]]
];)//RepeatedTiming
(* 1.7 seconds *) 

b == c
(* True *)
```