# How to speed up Outer[Subtract, vect1,vect2]?

Tags: performance-tuning

My Nbody code use a lot of  Outer[Subtract, vect1,vect2]. A lot means ten thousands to one hundred thousands times !! This is at the heart of my Nbody code, and I need to speed up this instruction. Each vector contains for example N=10000 values, and it scales like N^2.

By compiling this instruction , I obtain a factor of 4 faster (4 CPU !!). Not bad , but I dont want to buy 128 CPU !.

I dont understand for example why Outer[Times,vect1,vect2] is about 100 times faster than Outer[Subtract, vect1,vect2].It would be great to get this speed-up !

Is there a way to speed up Outer[Subtract, vect1,vect2]? Using C++, or using GPU , or else ??

Thank you for getting some advices.

Comment: Please see [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100551/a-quicker-than-outer) and the corresponding answers and comments.

Comment: This is an XY-problem. You are using an all-pairs algorithm which is inherintly $O(N^2)$. You should read about the [Barnes-Hut method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes–Hut_simulation) for $N$-body problems; it _approximates_ the correct result in $O(N \log(N))$ time and space.

Comment: Also have a look into the _Mathematica_ function [`NBodySimulation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NBodySimulation.html).

Comment: Even if you don't use Barnes-Hut: Using `Outer` leads to $O(N^2)$ memory consumption. And since the memory hierachy of this size rather slow, you should rather go for a (compiled!) double loop that needs only $O(N)$ memory to store the results (positions, velocities, forces).

Comment: Btw., you should rather use `Outer[Subtract, vect1,vect2,1]` (mind the fourth argument).

Comment: "why Outer[Times,vect1,vect2] is about 100 times faster than Outer[Subtract, vect1,vect2]":  For first arguments `Times`, `Plus`, and `List` and packed vectors for `vect1` and `vect2`, the reason is special-case implementations using SIMD and vectorization. For optimal speed, it is also important that you don't overflow CPU caches (N=10000 too big?). (`List` takes twice as long usually because it constructs an array that has twice as many entries as `Times` or `Plus`.) I think that a similar implementation for `Subtract` should be possible (in, say, C), but that's beyond my skillset to do so.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
x = RandomReal[1., 10000];
y = RandomReal[1., 10000];
a = Outer[Subtract, x, y]; // RepeatedTiming
b = Outer[Plus, x, -y]; // RepeatedTiming 
a == b
```

> {13.667, Null}

> {0.270628, Null}

> True

Comment: Relevant [answer from @ybeltukov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/100644/75628): _"Outer is highly optimized for several built-in functions (Plus, Times, List)"_.

Answer (score 5):

In case you want to do that for vector-valued data (because you mentiond N-body problems): `Outer` seems to be best optimized for scalar outputs. So working to "structure of arrays" format might be useful.

```
n = 10^4;
P = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 3}];
Q = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 3}];

RTimes = Outer[Times, P, Q, 1]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
RSubtract = Outer[Subtract, P, Q, 1]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
RMinus = Outer[Plus, P, -Q, 1]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 2.14531
>
> 15.3862
>
> 1.84677

Here the version that I mean. (I am using Karl's very good idea  here.)

```
(*Convert to structure of arrays format.*)
PT = Transpose[P];
QT = Transpose[Q];

(*Get result in structure of arrays format.*)
RT = {
  Outer[Plus, PT[[1]], -QT[[1]]], 
  Outer[Plus, PT[[2]], -QT[[2]]], 
  Outer[Plus, PT[[3]], -QT[[3]]]
}; // AbsoluteTiming // First

Dimensions[RT]

(*Convert to array of structures format (just for comparison; don't do that in your code!)*)
R = Transpose[RT, {3, 1, 2}];

Max[Abs[RMinus - R]]
```

> 0.350867
>
> {3, 10000, 10000}
>
> 0.

Nonetheless, you should rather use the Barnes-Hut method or the fast multipole method for approximating the interactions instead. There are a bazillion of code bases out there. Most of them will be written in *Fortran*, *C*, or *C++*, though. One *cannot* code them efficiently in an interpreted language like *Mathematica*. So I suggest you look for some *C++* library and link it with *LibraryLink*.

**Edit**

I also compared to a parallelized implementation in *C++* and even a blocked version (for avoiding cache misses). Both take about `0.143006` seconds. Single-threaded they do it in `0.325479`, which shows that this problem is likely memory bound. (I know from other experiments that two of my 8 CPU cores can fully satiate the memory bandwitdh of my machine.) So I don't think that you can get out much better performance here.

Comment: Thank you for this add to Karl's answer

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I can not explain what Outer with Subtract does. But if you do not use Outer you can get a similar performance as with Time by writing:

```
n = 10^4;
v1 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n];
v2 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n];

Outer[Times, v1, v2]; // AbsoluteTiming
Outer[Subtract, v1, v2]; // AbsoluteTiming
(v2 - #) & /@ v1; // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but your proposal doesnt give the same results ....

Comment: @RémyGalli `Transpose[Subtract[v1, #] & /@ v2]` should give the same as `Outer[Subtract, v1, v2]`

Comment: Simply exchange v1 and v2. I changed this in my answer.

Comment: @Sjoerd Smit   Thanks a lot. I gain a factor of 5. Any other idea ? By compiling for example ?

Comment: @DanielHuber It should be `Subtract[#, v2] & /@ v1`.