# Good way to create a similarity / distance matrix for a large dataset

Tags: matrix, dataset, distance

I have a large dataset with rows (100k+) for products and columns for features.

Now I want to create a similarity matrix with `NormalizedSquaredEuclideanDistance`. The desired output would be a symmetric matrix with products as columns and rows and the similarity measures as entries.

```
For[p = 1, p <= Length[dataset[[All,1]]], p++, 
  For[n = 1, n <= Length[dataset[[All,1]]], n++,
    SimMat[[p, n]] = 
      NormalizedSquaredEuclideanDistance[
        dataset[[n, 2 ;; Length[dataset[[n]]]]], 
        dataset[[p, 2 ;; Length[dataset[[p]]]]]]]
```

There are some problems:

1. `NormalizedSquaredEuclideanDistance` does not work with how I called the rows.
2. Using two For-loops for such a big dataset seems not very efficient,

Comment: I am finding it hard to understand this question. Can you give us a small example of input along with the output you expect from this example? By small, I mean an input matrix of dimension, say, 4 x 4.

Comment: Is your dataset / product-feature matrix sparse? For example, if you have 100 feature-columns, for a given product $p$ do all feature-columns have associating values with $p$?

Comment: It is sparse, as many columns are dummies for categorical features.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [(21861)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21861/121)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have *Mathematica* 10.3 or above you can use `DistanceMatrix`:

```
DistanceMatrix[dataset2, DistanceFunction -> NormalizedSquaredEuclideanDistance]
```

I'm assuming the same data as defined by kglr, you have not given us an example.
If you don't have *Mathematica* 10.3 there's still `` HierarchicalClustering`DistanceMatrix `` which is used in the same way.

Comment: I up-voted this answer because of the use of `DistanceMatrix`, but `DistanceMatrix` can be much slower than `Outer` for a list of sparse vectors.

Comment: @AntonAntonov. Thanks. Do you know why that is the case?

Comment: Sorry, no. I just did some benchmarking with `Outer` and `DistanceMatrix`.

Comment: @AntonAntonov but `DistanceMatrix` is orders of magnitude faster than `Outer` for normal matrices.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries May be it is a good idea to have an answer with benchmarking.

Answer (score 5):

```
dataset2 = RandomReal[1, {5, 7}]; (* this stands for dataset[[All,2;;]] in your case*)

dataset2 // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
output = Outer[NormalizedSquaredEuclideanDistance, dataset2, dataset2, 1];
output // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]