# How to efficiently implement k-FN (k-Furthest Neighbors)?

Tags: list-manipulation, computational-geometry

I'd like to pick *k* points from a set of points in *n*-dimensions that are approximately "maximally apart" (sum of pairwise distances is almost maxed). What is an efficient way to do this in MMA? Using the solution from C Woods, for example:

```
KFN[list_, k_Integer?Positive] := Module[{kTuples},
    kTuples=Subsets[RandomSample[list,Max[k*2,100]],{k}, 1000];
    MaximalBy[kTuples,Total[Flatten[Outer[EuclideanDistance[#1,#2]&,#,#,1]]]&]
]
pts=RandomReal[1,{100,3}]
kfn=KFN[pts,3][[1]]
Graphics3D[{Blue,Point[pts],PointSize[Large],Red,Point[kfn]}]
```

[image]

But here's the catch: I need this algorithm to be efficient enough to scale to this size:

```
pts=RandomReal[1,{10^6,10^3}];
kfn=KFN[pts,100]
Graphics3D[{Blue,Point[pts],PointSize[Large],Red,Point[kfn]}]
```

**Notes**

1. The comment from J.M. works for *k=2*, but hangs at *k=4*.
2. Here's a nice paper on k-FN:

   - http://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/workshops/ddr2012/papers/p3said.pdf

Comment: Like `With[{pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}}, pts[[#]] & /@ (Position[#, Max[#]] & @ UpperTriangularize[DistanceMatrix[pts]])]`?

Comment: How exactly are you defining "k-furthest neighbors" or "maximally apart?" Are you trying to maximize the sum of the pairwise distances among all k points? Or are you using some other metric?

Comment: @C.Woods Yes, sum of the pairwise distances among all k points.

Comment: Use dynamic programming and see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22424885/find-subset-of-size-k-such-that-the-minimum-distance-between-values-is-maximum

Comment: Your `KFN[]` makes the kernel crashed when fed the `RandomReal[1,{10^6,10^3}]` to it.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a naive solution that can be slow for large lists of points:

```
KFN[list_, k_Integer?Positive] := Module[{kTuples},
  kTuples = Subsets[list, {k}];
  MaximalBy[kTuples, 
   Total[Flatten[Outer[EuclideanDistance[#1, #2] &, #, #, 1]]] &]
  ]
```

(Use of `Subsets` function thanks to N.J. Evans. )
I'm not convinced there is a computationally "efficient" solution for this problem, but there are probably better algorithms than the one I have given you.

Comment: You can shorten some of this by using `Subsets[list,{2}]` instead of generating tuples, sorting, and deleting duplicates.

Comment: What about approximate KFN, like with Annoy?

Comment: Might be too slow `pts = RandomReal[1, {100, 3}]; kfn = KFN[pts, 5];` hangs

Comment: Your `Outer[]` construct is precisely what `DistanceMatrix[]` produces.

Comment: @J.M. My Outer[] construct also runs at 14.1642 seconds on a list of 1600 points as opposed to 17.3652 seconds for DistanceMatrix on the same list, so I am not in a hurry to change that.

Comment: @M.R. I am not sure about approximate algorithms, maybe someone else is familiar with that or else you might want to look up the literature on that and try it out.

Comment: How interesting. Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21863)?

Comment: @J.M. I had not. I tried this again with real numbers instead of integers and now DistanceMatrix is much faster. I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: @M.R. Care to explain the edit and the downvote?

Comment: @C.Woods my mistake!

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily best of quality but maybe could be made better with a bit of tuning.

```
kDistant[pts_List, n_] := Module[
  {objfun, len = Length[pts], ords, a, c1},
  ords = Array[a, n];
  c1 = Flatten[{Map[.5 <= # <= len + .5 &, ords], 
     Element[ords, Integers]}];
  objfun[oo : {_Integer ..}] := Module[
    {ovals = Clip[oo, {1, len}], ptlist, diffs},
    ptlist = pts[[ovals]];
    diffs = 
     Flatten[Table[
       ptlist[[j]] - ptlist[[k]], {j, n - 1}, {k, j + 1, n}], 1];
    Total[Map[Sqrt[#.#] &, diffs]]
    ];
  Round[NArgMax[{objfun[ords], c1}, ords, 
    Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", "SearchPoints" -> 40}, 
    MaxIterations -> 400]]
  ]
```

Example searching for 10 from 100000 points.

```
n = 10;
len = 10^5;
pts = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {len, 3}];

Timing[furthest = kDistant[pts, n]]

(* Out[6]= {15.85276, {34502, 90523, 79761, 66318, 53570, 18000, 80585, 
  12958, 87680, 70241}} *)
```

Seems to have done alright, points tend toward corners. Some pairs are close but that's probably an indication that the objective is not the best to use for `k` large.

```
Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[pts[[furthest]]]}]
```

[image]

--- edit ---

The variant below might be better for some purposes. Instead of maximizing a sum of all disatnce pairs it will maximize the sum of all minimum separations, which should have the effect of pushing all points away from one another. Some experimentation led me to increase iterations and also slightly up the number of points.

```
kDistantMins[pts_List, n_] := Module[
   {objfun, len = Length[pts], ords, a, c1},
   ords = Array[a, n];
   c1 = Flatten[{Map[.5 <= # <= len + .5 &, ords], 
      Element[ords, Integers]}];
   objfun[oo : {_Integer ..}] := Module[
     {ovals = Clip[oo, {1, len}], ptlist, diffs, dnorms, minnorms},
     ptlist = pts[[ovals]];
     diffs = 
      Table[ptlist[[j]] - ptlist[[k]], {j, n - 1}, {k, j + 1, n}];
     dnorms = Map[Sqrt[#.#] &, diffs, {2}];
     minnorms = Map[Min, dnorms];
     Total[minnorms]];
   Round[NArgMax[{objfun[ords], c1}, ords, 
     Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", "SearchPoints" -> 50}, 
     MaxIterations -> 1000]]
   ];
```

Whether this turns out to be an improvement will depend on the end goal I guess.

--- end edit ---

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to write the total distance between the `k` points as a quadratic form based on the `DistanceMatrix` `M`.  Finding the `k` points that maximise the total distance between them is then a matter of finding a vector `V` of zeros and ones that maximises `V.M.V` and whose total is `k` .

The following uses a literal implementation of this idea

```
kfn[list_, k_Integer?Positive] :=
 Module[{M, V, v, n, sol},
  n = Length[list];
  M = DistanceMatrix[list];
  V = Array[v, n];
  sol = NMaximize[{V.M.V, Total[V] == k, Thread[0 <= V <= 1], 
     Element[V, Integers]}, V];
  Pick[list, Thread[V == 1] /. Last[sol]]
  ]
```

This is not very useful.  It appears to be slower and less reliable than `KFN` by @C.Woods (repeated to make the answer self-contained)

```
KFN[list_, k_Integer?Positive] := Module[{kTuples},
  kTuples = Subsets[list, {k}];
  MaximalBy[kTuples, 
   Total[Flatten[Outer[EuclideanDistance[#1, #2] &, #, #, 1]]] &]
  ]
```

However, we can relax the requirement that the vector `V` contains only integers (but still have `0 <= V <= 1`), to give a function

```
candidate[list_, k_Integer?Positive] :=
 Module[{M, V, v, n, sol},
  n = Length[list];
  M = DistanceMatrix[list];
  V = Array[v, n];
  sol = FindMaximum[{V.M.V, Total[V] == k, Thread[0 <= V <= 1]}, V, 
    Gradient -> 2 M.V, Method -> "QuadraticProgramming"];
  Pick[list, Thread[V > 0.001] /. Last[sol]]
  ]
```

that picks out a list of points whose length is typically a little more than `k`.  Note that this is a concave/convex problem with a unique global solution.  When fed with this list of points `KFN` is much faster (and in limited testing, gives the same answer).  For example:

```
 pts = RandomReal[1, {100, 3}];
 AbsoluteTiming[KFN[pts, 3];]
 (* {1.78323, Null} *)
 AbsoluteTiming[KFN[candidate[pts, 3], 3];]
 (* {0.239304, Null} *)
 AbsoluteTiming[KFN[pts, 4];]
 (* {63.4595, Null} *)
 AbsoluteTiming[KFN[candidate[pts, 4], 4];]
 (* {0.306873, Null} *)
```

I have no proof that `candidate` is guaranteed to pick a subset containing the solution, but it seems plausible that it should give good (if not optimal) candidates.

This certainly won't scale to the higher number of points requested in the OP, but since the size of the optimisation problem is independent of the dimensionality of the space in which the points lie, it should cope with high dimensional spaces.