# How to return signed distance from DistanceMatrix?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, matrix, performance-tuning

Could someone confirm for me whether `DistanceMatrix` is behaving differently in V11?

In V10 I could return the signed differenced between two vectors using

```
DistanceMatrix[u,v,DistanceFunction->Subtract]
```

However, in V11 the returned values are all positive. Using an undefined function `f` for `DistanceFunction` reveals that `DistanceMatrix` is adding the `Abs` internally in V11 thus prohibiting signed returns:

```
DistanceMatrix[Range[2], Range[3], DistanceFunction -> f]
```

**V11 output**

> {{Abs[f[1, 1]], Abs[f[1, 2]], Abs[f[1, 3]]}, {Abs[f[2, 1]], 
>     Abs[f[2, 2]], Abs[f[2, 3]]}}

**V10.3 output**

> {{f[{1}, {1}], f[{1}, {2}], f[{1}, {3}], f[{2}, {1}], f[{2}, {2}], 
>     f[{2}, {3}]}}

I feel like including `Abs` by default isn't very helpful as I could always add it in if I wanted it!

Thus I have two questions:

1. Is there any way to remove it? I
2. Is there a smarter way to get the signed differences of two lists - I know I can use `Outer` but have been using `DistanceMatrix` following the discussion [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21861/6588)

Comment: Relevant? Doesn't use `Outer` http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21861/fastest-way-to-calculate-matrix-of-pairwise-distances

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack, and I am not sure how it will impact performance, but it goes around the "improvement" put in place in v.11:

```
ReleaseHold[
 DistanceMatrix[Range[2], Range[3], DistanceFunction -> HoldForm[Subtract]] /. Abs[a_] :> a
]

(* Out: {{0, -1, -2}, {1, 0, -1}} *)
```

Compare to the built-in in v.11:

```
DistanceMatrix[Range[2], Range[3], DistanceFunction -> Subtract]

(* Out: {{0, 1, 2}, {1, 0, 1}} *)
```

Comment: A similar hack:  `Block[{Abs = Identity},
 DistanceMatrix[Range[2], Range[3], DistanceFunction -> Subtract]
 ]`

Comment: @JasonB Your suggestion is arguably more elegant as well.

Comment: `ReleaseHold` and `Block` both great ways to get around the issue, thanks. `ReleaseHold` suffers a performance hit whereas `Block` does not.

Answer (score 4):

`Outer` is pretty fast when used with `Plus` so I daresay `Outer[Plus, u, -v]` will be competitive:

```
u = Range[1000];
v = Range[2000];

RepeatedTiming[
 a = DistanceMatrix[u, v, DistanceFunction -> Subtract];]
(* {0.499, Null} *)

RepeatedTiming[
 b = Outer[Plus, u, -v];]
(* {0.00918, Null} *)

Abs[b] == a
(* True *)
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out that `Outer[Plus, u, -v]` is orders of magnitude faster than `Outer[Subtract, u, v]`. I like the methods of circumventing the `Abs` issue in MarcoB's answer but the Outer Plus route is by far the fastest! And what I'll use form now on!